# Overlapping content issue with responsive background image div and fixed nav

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, margin, overlap

I have a fixed nav and underneath is a background image contained inside a responsive div so it resizes proportionally. Using padding-bottom = image height/width * 100 to make it responsive. There's a content section below that which has to be pulled up to overlap that background image div. I've tried a negative bottom margin on the background div and negative top margin on the content div for that. When you shrink the screen down, the negative margin starts pulling the content under the fixed nav and above the screen out of view. It needs to stay in view at least a minimum distance below the fixed nav. What's the best way to do that? A pure CSS solution is preferred if possible, but I can use jQuery if it isn't. Thanks for the help.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ow9y41g/

```css
 #fixed-nav {
        top: 0;
        background: #EEE;
        position: fixed;
        min-height: 2em;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      #fixed-nav ul {
        display: flex;
        list-style-type: none;
      }
      
      #fixed-nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      #background {
        background: orange;
        padding-bottom: 30%; /* padding-bottom = height/width * 100% */
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      #background h2 {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
        padding-top: 4em;
      }
      
      #content {
        margin-top: -18em;
      }
```

```html
<div id="fixed-nav">
          <ul>
            <li>Nav Link One</li>
            <li>Second Nav Link</li>
            <li>Another Nav Link</li>
            <li>The Last Link</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="background">
          <h2>div with background image</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
          <h1>Page content overlaps</h1>
          
          <p>background-image padding-bottom = height/width * 100 for responsive 
            background image</p>
            
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolour sit met, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed various 
              libero elit, iaculis consectetur justo dignissim eu. Suspendisse potenti. 
              Cras ullamcorper, felis quis molestie dignissim, nunc dui interdum metus, 
              ut laoreet odio risus eget libero.  Nullam sed iaculis metus. Fusce vestibulum 
              justo mauris, eu imperdiet tortor iaculis et. Duis volutpat porta ligula 
              sit amet vehicula. Donec iaculis aliquam ullamcorper. Suspendisse vitae 
              pharetra libero.</p>
              
              <p>Nullam enim mauris, hendrerit quis varius id, vehicula id dui. Praesent 
                varius lacus id faucibus rhoncus.Suspendisse potenti. Cras ullamcorper, 
                felis quis molestie dignissim, nunc dui interdum metus, ut laoreet odio 
                risus eget libero. Nullam sed iaculis metus. Fusce vestibulum justo mauris. 
                Praesent semper sed lectus in volutpat. Sed urna lectus, sodales vel 
                pharetra vitae, commodo vel orci. Vestibulum ante mauris, ultricies et magna at, 
                dictum suscipit nulla. Praesent libero metus, blandit eu hendrerit vel, 
                maximus et nunc.</p>
              </div>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me in which media series it's overlapping.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you just used `background-img` and background-size: cover` for your `div#content` element, and use margin offset the `div#fixed-nav`?  This way you would eliminate the `div#background` element completely.

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7ow9y41g/1/) the effect you are after?

Comment: It's close but not quite, the background image has to resize proportionally so that all of it is always 100% visible. So I can't use background-size: cover on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue by placing your `<div id="content"></div>` inside the `<div id="background"></div>`. For example:

```
<div id="background">

 <div id="content">
   margin-top: 0; 
 </div>

</div>
```

for some reason you dont want to do that, you can also do following by setting content div position to absolute and top: 50px; but than i will recommend to set z-index of your nav bar so it can stay on top.. for example:

```
#fixed-nav {
  top: 0;
  background: #EEE;
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}


#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Hope it helps.
Happy Coding, and happy holidays!

Comment: I think this gave me the right idea. Instead of using a static value like top: 50px, I can do a calculation so the content moves up as the background images shrinks, but not so quickly that it goes up out of the screen. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/h1u4zfyt/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, the other way you suggested works even better, but instead of the content div inside the background div, I have the background div inside the content. I then use absolute positioning to keep the background at the top of the screen and the content stays where it's supposed to be. There's actually a second background image div below the content as well that I position similarly. Thanks for the idea, it got me on the right track.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you! Happy coding and merry christmas.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but, I think you need to add the height. Here's my code:

```
#fixed-nav {
    top: 0;
    background: #EEE;
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 2em;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#background {
    background: orange;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#content {
    margin-top: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Hope that helps. If not, you need to elaborate on the specifics.

Comment: This looks like it would have a background image with a fixed height, but I need it to be responsive so it shrinks and grows proportionally with the browser, hence the padding-bottom trick for the height of the background div. I was going for more of something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/h1u4zfyt/

Answer (score 0):

Use `height` option for `#fixed-nav` instead of `min-height`.

Then, use `margin-top:|fixed-nav's height|` option for the first element which has 'position:relative' *(in your code = `#background`)*.

And, there is no need to define `margin` value for `#content`...just use `position: relative`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#fixed-nav {
  top: 0;
  background: #EEE;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

#fixed-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#fixed-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

#background {
  background: orange;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#background h2 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)
}

#content {
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Nav Link One</li>
    <li>Second Nav Link</li>
    <li>Another Nav Link</li>
    <li>The Last Link</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="background">
  <h2>div with background image</h2>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <h1>Page content overlaps</h1>
  <p>background-image padding-bottom = height/width * 100 for responsive background image</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed varius libero elit, iaculis consectetur justo dignissim eu. Suspendisse potenti. Cras ullamcorper, felis quis molestie dignissim, nunc dui interdum metus, ut laoreet odio risus eget libero.<br/>Nullam sed iaculis metus. Fusce vestibulum justo mauris, eu imperdiet tortor iaculis et. Duis volutpat porta ligula sit amet vehicula. Donec iaculis aliquam ullamcorper. Suspendisse vitae pharetra libero.</p>
  <p>Nullam enim mauris, hendrerit quis varius id, vehicula id dui. Praesent varius lacus id faucibus rhoncus.Suspendisse potenti. Cras ullamcorper, felis quis molestie dignissim, nunc dui interdum metus, ut laoreet odio risus eget libero. Nullam sed iaculis metus.<br/>Fusce vestibulum justo mauris. Praesent semper sed lectus in volutpat. Sed urna lectus, sodales vel pharetra vitae, commodo vel orci. Vestibulum ante mauris, ultricies et magna at, dictum suscipit nulla. Praesent libero metus, blandit eu hendrerit vel, maximus et nunc.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. In your example, the background image isn't responsive. It stays the same height as it shrinks. It's height/width need to shrink proportionally when the browser is resized. This is more like what I was trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/h1u4zfyt/

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I changed height value to min-height. And moved padding value for h2 to parent div's style. Please run code snippet again.